# how to integrate code with virtualbox?

Tags: c++, virtualization, virtualbox

i am doing project in virtualbox. i have a client and server code in c++. i want server code to be integrated with virtualbox source code. client is sending cd image to server and cd image is diaplayed as virtual cdrom in guest os. i am trying to integrate this cd image with virtual cdrom part of vbox. but i dont know where to integrate this such that while running guest os, cd appears in it. it should NOT BE DONE MANUALLY. dont know where to put this cd image such that it will apperas in guest os. it would be a great help if u sort out this problem .

Answer (score 3):

Simplest, your server can run the shell command [`VBoxManage storageattach`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp14186624) to eject or attach cdrom images to a virtualbox guest.